# Change the Google interface language

Tags: google-account, localization

I know this will sound as a strange question, but I looked everywhere - and I cannot find the problem.

When I am logged in, for any google service that I use, Google thinks my default language is Greek (which is not my language at all). This means the following

- the whole Google interface is translated to Greek
- the is true for AdWords, AdSense, analytics, webmaster tools, recaptcha service, ...
- this is not related to browser/computer as I tried other computers and browsers (Firefox and Chrome).
- I see in any Google URL that "?hl=el" is added (which forces Google to use Greek)
- the only way to stop this, is manually change "?hl=el" to "?hl=nl" (Dutch language) Deleting the "?hl=el" doesn't help, I need to change it.

This is related to my personal account. But I cannot find an option to change this setting. I can't remember setting this myself.

I have multiple Google accounts, and this is only on one specific account (sadly, my most important).

Question is clear: How do I change this?

Comment: https://www.google.com/webhp?hl=en

Answer (score 10):

Google provides a language setting per Google-account.

Since this page will likely be in Greek for you, I'll quote it below:
https://support.google.com/accounts/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=32047

> To change the display language for Google Accounts, you'll need to change your Google interface language:
>
> 1. Visit your Accounts settings page. (https://www.google.com/accounts)
> 2. Click the Language tab.
> 3. Use the drop-down box to select your primary language, and click "Add another   language" if you'd like other options.
>
> Once you've changed your interface language, close the browser window. Then, open your browser and visit https://www.google.com/accounts/. The Google Accounts homepage should be displayed in the language you've selected.
>
> If the interface language doesn't match the language you selected, please clear your browser's cache and cookies (http://www.google.com/support/accounts/bin/answer.py?answer=32050) and try setting the interface language again. Note that deleting your cookies will also remove your saved settings for other sites you've visited.
>
> Keep in mind that while the Google Accounts homepage is available in all Google languages, individual Google products may not be available in all languages.

Comment: +1 for realizing that the OP won't be able to see the page in a language he can understand.

Answer (score 3):

Changing the interface language of the Google products has clearly two answers: 
change the language of your account (as described by @JochemKuijpers) or changing/adding a url parameter (as described by @user13664).
 I like the url parameter because it's handy to test or give support to a multilingual user group, especially when different scripts are used (as roman versus greek or arabic etc).
It would be nice if all google applications worked the same way and were well documented. For now you have to test and try.

- search: https://google.com/webhp?hl=en (thanks @STTR)
- email: https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/?hl=en does not work,
- email, new version: https://inbox.google.com/?hl=en works
- youtube: https://www.youtube.com/?hl=en works (you need to confirm)
- drive: https://drive.google.com/drive/my-drive?hl=en does not work
- sites, old version: https://sites.google.com/?hl=en does not work
- sites, new version: https://sites.google.com/new?hl=en works
- photos: https://photos.google.com/?hl=en works
- support: https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/32047?hl=en works

see also https://sites.google.com/site/tomihasa/google-language-codes
note: I did not test for all languages

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/?hl=en does not seem to work, I can't get hl=de, hl=el, hl=sv to work. But gl=GB, gl=IN does permanently change the region, so I would expect this kind of code to work (hl is usually temporary), but apparently not.

Answer (score 0):

https://www.google.com/settings/account - there you can set a primary language

Answer (score 0):

go to     https://www.google.com/preferences 
Now select the language tab. Change the language to English and press save.